# Demo account which resets itself

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, ruby-on-rails-3.2, saas

What is the best the best approach to provide visitors with a demo account?

The demo account has to have some basic demo data and has to reset itself after a certain amount of time.

Answer (score 1):

With devise you can set up a guest user. Or implement a test user with the seed.rb then you can add custom datas to this user.

[This is a sample howto in the devise wiki](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Create-a-guest-user)